# Richfaces vs Primefaces : Cannot read property 'requests' of undefined

Tags: javascript, primefaces, richfaces, compatibility

I'm developping a web application in JSF that uses Richfaces 4.3.0 CRI and Primefaces 3.4.2.
I've just notified that on any page that uses Primefaces components, I can see in the Javascript console this error happened:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'requests' of undefined packed.js:3243

But the packed.js file is the one included in the Richfaces library package. But on each page that doesn't use a Primefaces component, this error doesn't occur.

Problem is sometimes, this error makes stop working some others Javascript code (other functions are aborted).

I wonder if it exists a way to fix it or a work around? I just want to avoid that other scripts become aborted because of this error.

Comment: I think this comes from the delivered jquery libraries(version) rich and prime uses. Because  they are not the same. But a page can only load 1 jquery library. I have eliminated rich to replace with prime because incompatibility issues when using both.

Comment: Thank you, you was right, it comes from the delivered jquery libraries but no need to eliminate anything.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, and obviously, it was a problem of compatibility because Richfaces and Primefaces don't use the same version of jquery.js.
But thanks to this article: [Working towards RichFaces(4.2.2-Fianl) / PrimeFaces(3.3) compatibility](http://yyq2007aa.blog.163.com/blog/static/44181609201242794212780/), I solved the problem.
But it seems to work only for the version of RichFaces and Primefaces used in the article. Not with the most recent versions.